# Setting items per page in Django Tastypie Paginator

Tags: django, tastypie, paginator

I am trying to add a custom paginator to my Django API but I am not sure how can I limit the number of items per page in paginator_class in get_sdc_data().

```
class CustomApplicationSDCResource(AppMapBaseResource):
    class Meta(AppMapBaseResource.Meta):
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        queryset = Applications.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'applications'
        allowed_methods = {'get'}
        allowed_models = ['Applications']
        paginator_class = Paginator


    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/get_sdc_data%s$" % \
             (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_sdc_data'), name="api_get_sdc_data"),
       ]


    def get_sdc_data(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            sdc_list = []
            limit=request.GET.get('limit')
            next_item = request.GET.get('next')
            if request.GET.has_key('uaid'):
               search_uaid=request.GET.get('uaid')
               sdc_obj = Applications.objects.filter(Q(uaid__contains=search_uaid, status='Active'))
            else:
               sdc_obj = Applications.objects.all()
            exc=['vendor_name', 'ldrps_app_rto','alias_name']
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
            sdc_list = [model_to_dict(obj, exclude=exc) for obj in sdc_obj]
            paginator = self._meta.paginator_class(request.GET, sdc_list, resource_uri=self.get_resource_uri(), \
            limit=limit, max_limit=self._meta.max_limit, collection_name=self._meta.collection_name)
            paginated = paginator.page()
            paginated['Applications'] = paginated.pop('objects')
            return self.create_response(request, {"result" : paginated})
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Problem in getting SDC Applications data. Error is ' + str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is slicing the filter queryset.

```
# Pseudocode
offset = request.get('offset', 0)
limit = request.get('limit', 10)
obj_queryset = Instance.objects.filter(foo=bar)[offset:limit]
```

So from client just tell the paginated set required.
Hope this helps.